# why cant Login to AD OU user with GPO to the local server machine itself?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, login

I had installed windows 2022 server eval version and windows 11 evalution version  in clients. I had configured active directory . I hade created Organisational unit. Then applied Group policy in organisation units.

all users and the GP policy restrictions are working fine on clients.

But i want to lock the server machine itself with it . I had login with the administrator account on server machine.

But when i try to login with other user with GPO applied whenever i login with other user on server it say that the user login is restricted to login on server. i cant login any other user except the administrator

How to  remove resetriction or give permission to single user  for logging in to server or can i  diffrent OU  create 1 local user in windows server 2022 with user limited ristrictions and GPO applied to login the server machine itself

Thanks in advance for giving precisous time for reading  the question and replying and sharing your knoweldge and helping.

Comment: this should explain what you need to know [Allow log on locally - security policy setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/allow-log-on-locally)

Comment: @jfrmilner thanks buddy tried and it worked thank you a lots